# How to create the parent and a set of children at the same time in a To-Many Relationship in Core Data

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I have a To-Many Relationship between `Car` and `Tire` in `Core Data` where a car can have 2, 4, or 6 tires. I'm a little tricked by the fact that I need to create the tires when the car is created and saved to Core Data. In the past, I have worked with this type of relationship in Core Data but I never had the need to create the children objects at the same time as the parent. Please note that parent and children objects will be entered from a `FormView` and the user will be selecting both at the same time.

How is this typically handled, how do you pass a set of custom `Core Data` objects from a view to the service model to be able to create the parent and a set of children at the same time in a To-Many Relationship in Core Data?

I get an error when I try to pass the array of `Tires` from the view as shown in the code below.

#### ENTITIES/Attributes:

##### Car

- model:String
- tires: Relationship: Destination->Tire/Inverse->Car

##### Tire

- type:String
- isSolid:Bool
- car: Relationship: Destination->Car/Inverse->tires

#### Service Model

```
    class CarServiceModel: ObservableObject{
            
        let manager: CoreDataManager
        
        @Published var cars: [Car] = []
        
        init(coreDataManager: CoreDataManager = .instance){
            self.manager = coreDataManager
            loadCars()
        }
        
        func updateCloudKitContainer(){
            manager.container = manager.setupContainer()
        }
        
        func addCar(model:String?, tires:[Tire]?){
            let newCar = Car(context: manager.context)
            newCar.model = model ?? ""

            // create tires
            if tires != nil{
                for t in tires ?? [Tire](){
                    let tire = Tire(context: manager.context)
                    tire.type = t.type
                    tire.isSolid = t.isSolid

                    tire.car = newCar
                }
            }
            save()
            loadCars()
        }

        func save(){
            self.manager.save()
        }
    }
```

#### View

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        @StateObject private var carServiceVM = CarServiceModel()
        
        var body: some View {
                Button {
                    let tire1 = Tire(context: manager.context)
                    tire1.type = "All Season"
                    tire1.isSolid = false
                    
                    let tire2 = Tire(context: manager.context)
                    tire2.type = "Snow"
                    tire2.isSolid = false
                    
                    var tempTiresArray:[Tire] = [Tire]()
                    tempTiresArray.append(tire1)
                    tempTiresArray.append(tire2)
                    
                    carServiceVM.addCar(name: "Model S", tires: tempTiresArray)
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "car")
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                        .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                }
        }
    }
```

#### Error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Tire setName:]:

Comment: Not related to your error (maybe there's a constraint in Core Data for these entities?), but do you realize you are duplicating the tires? The button creates 2 tires, then the `addCar()` function duplicates them, the last ones are mounted in the car. The `addCar()` function could simply call `t.car = newCar`.

Comment: First of all, I don't really understand why you create new tires for each car. Does each car really have to have its now unique snow tire for instance? Secondly, what you are doing with Tire objects where you create new objects both in the Button action and then in the addCar is not only unnecessary but could also be a potential reason for your crash. I would personally create all entity objects inside the addCar method and pass the tire data as some array parameter.

Comment: @HunterLion - Shoot, I just realized that in my code I left something I was testing after the error, my code shows `let tire1 = Tire(context: manager.context)` and I really had `let tire1 = Tire()`.  After trying and using `Tire(context: manager.context)` the error when away and you're absolutely right, it duplicates the entries. **Now the question is, is it really necessary to use `contex:` when declaring Core Data objects?** I was under the impression that they could be declared as normal objects, without `contex:`. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - What I'm presenting here is not what I'm really doing, the car tires is just a simplified example, but in my real application, I really need to create different children every time since are objects with doubles that are used to make calculations. You're absolutely right, crating objects inside the view is not what I want and is basically where my confusion is, how do I pass the tire objects so they're created inside the `addCar()` method inside the VM/service class? If I remove `context: manager.context` when I create the `Tire` objects in the view is when I get the error.

Comment: I would personally create a struct to hold the Tire attribute values and then pass an array of such objects to addCar and convert them to Tire objects there. Or go the other way and do everything in the view, I don't favour this but it is still better than splitting the work between the view and the model class.

Comment: Depending on how your view works and the editing of objects is done it might be worth working with a NSManagedObjectContext parent/child solution.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson -  Ah ok, got it, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way to handle this.  Thanks a lot for your input.